# How to install mssql module for nodejs offline

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I need to install mssql module in an environment where internet connection is not available. I already have node version 0.10.0 installed.  I'm specifically looking for an offline installer for node.js.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I did a lot of search on the internet but could not find an offline installer for the same or a way to do in the given situation.


I only found the command

'npm install mssql'

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an internet connection in the environment you are working on then you can do one thing, download the modules in your project in an environment where you can an internet connection.

The files are downloaded in a folder /node_modules where your project is present.

Copy the content from this to the environment where you want to use them.

Worked for me.